# Using a list of ids from a column to create a list of names to save to another

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has a column that contains a list of ids:
1234,2345,3456

Each of those ids is the primary key to one of the rows in this same table.

Each row has a name field. How can I change the id list to a name list?

```
ID,   NAME,  IDLIST    
----------------------    
1234, name1, (null)    
2345, name2, 1234,2345    
3456, name3, 1234,3456
```

using the above idList for each column would create a new list:

nameList for 2345 = name1,name2

nameList for 3456 = name1,name3

The particular dialect of SQL doesn't matter, I'm just trying to find if this can be done in a single Update.

Comment: Fix your data structure.  If you use bogus data representations, then the code is much much harder than necessary.  You should have a select table with one row for each pair of ids.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for the suggestion. Any suggestion for a better way of representing a scenario like this? Basically, each item can have a parent item, and that list represents each parent in the chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution (MySQL, for Oracle change GROUP_CONCAT to WMSYS.WM_CONCAT)

Preparation:

```
create table tmp_table(
    id int,
    name varchar(5),
    idslist varchar(20)
);

insert into tmp_table(id, name, idslist) values(
    1234,
    'name1',
    null
);
insert into tmp_table(id, name, idslist) values(
    2345,
    'name2',
    '1234,2345'
);
insert into tmp_table(id, name, idslist) values(
    3456,
    'name3',
    '1234,3456'
);
```

Query:

```
select 
    t1.id, t1.name, t1.idslist, GROUP_CONCAT(distinct t2.name) 
from 
    tmp_table t1 
    LEFT JOIN tmp_table t2 ON t1.idslist like CONCAT('%', t2.id, '%') 

GROUP BY t1.id, t1.name, t1.idslist
;
```

result:

```
1234    name1       
2345    name2   1234,2345   name1,name2
3456    name3   1234,3456   name3,name1
```

It works, but may cause troubles if you have id, say, 12 and 1234.

I'd advise you to use many-to-many relation table. If you need order, you can add order field, it will be something like

```
+----------+---------------------+
| child_id | parent_id | position|
+----------+---------------------+
| 2345     | 1234      |   1     |
| 2345     | 2345      |   2     |
+----------+---------------------+
```